# EntityFramework 5 multiple joins

Tags: join, include, entity-framework-5

This page shows nicely how to cope with different scenario's for fetching data: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg671236%28v=vs.103%29.aspx

**How do I select *a collection* and *two references*?** (Lines have a ProductId and an AddressId, I want to include both...)

In other words, where do I put my `Level1Reference2` in:

> `query.Include(e => e.Lines.Select(l1 => l1.Level1Reference))` // Level1Reference2?

- To include **a single reference**: `query.Include(e => e.Level1Reference)`
- To include **a single collection**: `query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection)`
- To include **a reference** and then **a reference one level down**: `query.Include(e => e.Level1Reference.Level2Reference)`
- To include **a reference** and then **a collection one level down**: `query.Include(e => e.Level1Reference.Level2Collection)`
- To include **a collection** and then **a reference one level down**: `query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection.Select(l1 => l1.Level2Reference))`
- To include **a collection** and then **a collection one level down**: `query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection.Select(l1 => l1.Level2Collection))`
- To include **a collection** and then **a reference one level down**: `query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection.Select(l1 => l1.Level2Reference))`
- To include **a collection**, **a reference**, and **a reference two levels down**: `query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection.Select(l1 => l1.Level2Reference.Level3Reference))`
  To include **a collection**, **a collection**, and **a reference two levels down**: `query.Include(e => e.Level1Collection.Select(l1 => l1.Level2Collection.Select(l2 => l2.Level3Reference)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just repeat an Include:

```
query.Include(e => e.Lines.Select(l1 => l1.Level1Reference))
     .Include(e => e.Lines.Select(l1 => l1.Level1Reference2))
```